# React Native - Firebase custom events are not logged in the console

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-analytics

I have an application developed in React Native that correctly sends the events to Firebase in Android and in IOS <14 but in versions higher than 14 it does not register the custom events but the default events.

In debug mode with IOS 15 and IOS> 14 the events are registered correctly, but when testing from the TestFlight the events are not registered, I have already waited for several days and the events are not registered

The app has the ATT permission implemented, the user is asked for permission to activate the tracking

async requestPermissionsTransparency() {
if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY).then(async (statuses :any) => {
switch (statuses[PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY]) {
case RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE || RESULTS.GRANTED:
await Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true).then( async (result) => {
Settings.initializeSDK();
});
await firebase.analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
break;
}
});
}
}

package.json
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.64.2",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^12.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.4.0",

PodFile
platform :ios, '14.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

Has anyone been through this problem? some configuration is needed for it to work in release mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe 'RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true' in your podfile? I am encountering the same issue and I use this setting in my podfile.

I removed the setting, so I hope that that is the solution. I can't update my app to testflight at this moment to test if this works. In a few weeks I will test it and then I let you know.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I'll try adding this setting in my pod file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32883805)